# Asp.net upload image doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am currenlty stuck on a small project. Here is my code;

```
 String StuPicc =  Server.MapPath("images/" + UploadPic.FileName);
 UploadPic.SaveAs(StuPicc);
```

UploadPic is the control name. But, neither it display the name nor upload the selected image.
When i output the result on a label it display;

```
images/{image name isn't showing here}
```

Any help regard to this will be apreciatable.

Comment: do you get any error? try use "~/images/" + UploadPic.FileName

Comment: What is a class of UploadPic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a file upload control then..FileUploadControl ID="FuImage" file upload control..and uploaded files will be saved in  "UploadedFiles" folder.

```
   string path = "\\UploadedFiles\\" + Guid.NewGuid() + FuImage.FileName;
    FuImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") + path);
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control?  I believe the filename is available from the inputfile property then, although the only code I have used is to retrieve the stream:

```
System.Drawing.Image i = 
System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(flUploader.PostedFile.InputStream);
```

`flUploader.PostedFile.Filename` should be valid along with the input stream if the upload is occuring.